# RestTemplate GET exchange with Set<Long> parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two services (A and B). I want to send a GET request from service A to service B. Here how my request looks like (Service A):

```
public Set<StudentDTO> getStudentsByIds(Set<Long> ids) {  //here may be a set of ids [123213L, 435564L]
    return restTemplate.exchange("localhost:8090/students/all?ids={ids}",
        HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(ids), new ParameterizedTypeReference<Set<StudentDTO>>() {}, ids).getBody();
}
```

Here how my Service B controller looks like:

```
@RequestMapping("/students")
public class StudentController {
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public Set<StudentDTO> getStudentsByIds(@RequestParam Set<Long> ids) {
        return studentService.getStudentsByIds(ids);
    }

}
```

I am having trouble with sending set as parameter. I guess we can't put Set as parameter. I tried already turning set to String and removing the brackets from it like following and it worked:

```
String ids = ids.toString().substring(1, ids.toString().length() - 1);
```

But maybe there better solution or is there any solution to send Set?

My url looks like this: `localhost:8090/students/all?ids=id1&ids=id2&ids=id3`

Comment: to pass as a list or set in an url you need an url like this ->  localhost:8090/students/all?ids=id1,id2,id3,etc, or like this localhost:8090/students/all?ids=id1&ids=id2&ids=id3.

Comment: @Anon Yes, I have url like this.

Comment: If you are potentially going to have a large set, it's probably better to change your method to POST or a PUT so that you can put the  parameters into the body of the request as JSON. Doing so is not strictly RESTful, but to me, makes more sense in a situation like this.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek No, I exactly need Get because of documentation, and I will have no more than 5 values in set.

Comment: i did some tests this url should do what you want "http: //localhost:8090/students/all?ids="  put this on the restTemplate.exchange.  Note i also change the Sets to Lists the url has a space after the http: just remove the space

Comment: @Anon So there is no way to send Set itself, I need to convert it to List?

Comment: @Anon But it does not send nothing with such way ("http://localhost:8090/students/all?ids="). I converted to List, but didn't get nothing in Service 2. There is no any values.

Comment: weird because i tested with 2 controllers and one service and going from controller A to the service then it call the  controller B and it gave me the result i was expecting and i used the same code you gave me just with Lists and the url change also dont forget to write the http://  at the start or it will give an error

Comment: if you are still having problems i can do an answer with some code that will help you with this

Comment: @Anon Yes, I added http:// . Maybe it will be more clear with some code, thanks.

Comment: i was wrong sorry but you can do what skidwiz posted since its correct or you can just create a string variable to store the ids and the used that for the uriVariables like this.
 
String urlIds = ids.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(","));

restTemplate.exchange("http: //localhost:8090/students/all?ids={urlIds}",
                HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(ids), new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<StudentDTO>>() {}, urlIds).getBody();

Answer (score 3):

Your url is being formed incorrectly.  By using `all?ids={ids}` the resulting url sent to the service layer is `http://localhost:8090/students/all?ids=%5B23677,%2012345,%201645543%5D`.  This is because the brackets from the set are being added to the url, but aren't interpreted properly.  You can fix this by sending it as a comma delimited String appended to the URL, like this.

```java
public Set<Long> getStudentsByIds(Set<Long> ids){
    String studentIdsUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api/all?ids=" + ids.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    return restTemplate.exchange(studentIdsUrl,
        HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(ids), new ParameterizedTypeReference<Set<Long>>() {}, ids).getBody();
}
```